# How do I programatically download bank of America transactions?

Tags: gif, bank, ofx

I use quicken, which can automatically download bank of America transactions. However, it truncates all the payees so I lose data. I'd like to work around this and I'm thinking of downloading the transaction data and generating my own QFX file with the full payee info.

Is there a way that I can download transactions programmatically, or download something like a .qif (available on their website) programmatically? For the latter, I could convert the gif to a QFX myself.

If anyone has other ideas to download all of the transaction information without losing the payee info, I would welcome those ideas as well.

Comment: Haven't clicked on the first answer's link but I am guessing you'll need an api key first, which will give you access you your accounts or any that you are authorized for. I highly doubt BOA would just throw up an api that will let you query other people's banking info. BTW how are you putting up 50 rep when you only have 35?

Comment: Citibank has the same problem.  "ACH Electronic Debit - VERIZON WIRELESS PAYMENTS" gets truncated to "ACH Electronic Debit - VERI" in the .qfx file and then down to "- VERI" in quicken itself.  I'm considering downloading the .qfx file and .csv file (which does not truncate) and then recombining.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the API will return a JSON so you may need to find a tool to convert that to a qif or qfx if that part is important. After digging further, I can't test this without having a CashPro account but it *seems* what you need to do is...

Step 1:

- Get an access token from [here](https://developer.bankofamerica.com/#/getAccess/wizard). You'll need to send this in the header of any requests

Step 2:

- Send an http request with a header in the following format:

  ```
   {
   "accounts": [
     {
      "accountNumber": "xxxxxxx",
      "bankId": "xxxxxxx"
     }
    ],
   "fromDate": "yyyy-mm-dd",
   "toDate": "yyyy-mm-dd"
   }
  ```

to https://developer.bankofamerica.com/cashpro/reporting/v1/transaction-inquiries/previous-day

Step 3:

- You should get a JSON as a response

As mentioned, I can't test this but [here's the documentation](https://developer.bankofamerica.com/#/api/account-information/cashpro-reporting-v1-transaction-inquiries-previous-day-post) of the specific API endpoint you need

Comment: CashPro is for Commercial Banking.  My guess is that Quicken user has only Personal accounts, so these APIs won't help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for `bank of america api` yielded this [BofA API](https://developer.bankofamerica.com/#/home). They even have many options for types of payment information you could query [here](https://developer.bankofamerica.com/#/api/payments) as well as lots of individual account types that you can access it as.

It looks pretty comprehensive. If you don't see what you are looking for there I put another option below, just in case.

I don't use BofA. So I can't speak to what they have natively available. But you could always use a bot to scrape it if they present it anywhere in the User Interface.

I would agree with Meena that you should not be able to use curl. But selenium uses a browser to programmatically do just about anything that you would want to do with any website. They also have bindings for many languages. So you could just pick your favorite and go to town...

Answer (score -1):

There are two options that you have, neither of which is easy! Both require coding ability.

**Option ONE** is to figure out how to use Plaid.com and create an app that can connect and pull the transactions thru Plaid's system.
And just an FYI, for Bank of America, you will need to apply to be approved for Production mode in order to use OAuth mode access. Production mode is not free, but is pretty cheap, like $0.30 per year per account. I started trying to work this out, but have not been able to figure out how to write the code to do the Linking and OAuth of account yet.

**Option TWO** is to write some code that can scrape the site for you, and automatically download the transactions. Python is usually the preferred language to do this in.
I found the following (have not tried any of them):

https://www.neilgrogan.com/bank-tx-py/

https://github.com/search?q=bankofamerica&type=repositories

https://github.com/search?q=bank+of+america&type=repositories

https://github.com/Wllew4/bofa_scraper

https://github.com/rusdog2784/bank_of_america

Comment: Link-only answers are not valid answers. Aside from that: the original question is off-topic - it's just a set of requirements, no effort shown, and no specific programming question.